# Grails non-existent mapping property

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Having problems with domain class mappings. The domains are as follows:

**User Domain**

```
class User extends SecUser {
   static hasMany = [ratings:Rating, searchedResults:Results, recommendedResults:Results]
   static mappedBy = [searchedResults:"searched", recommendedResults:"recommended"]
}
```

**Rating Domain**

```
class Rating {
   static belongsTo = User

   Artist artist
   double rating
}
```

**Results Domain**

```
class Results {
   static belongsTo = User

   def searched
   def recommended
}
```

When compiling it gives following error:

```
 Non-existent mapping property [recommended] specified for property [recommendedResults] in class [class ontourtest.User].
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `def searched` and `def recommended` in the `Results` class to their actual types (example `Thing searched`, `Thing recommended`). I'm not sure what type they're supposed to be and i think grails doesn't know either.

See the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html)

Note: there is a type-o in the documentation ;)